# Is this in the form of a geometric series?

Tags: geometric-series

Is the equation below a geometric series? I think yes but the only thing that bothers me is the $1+$ in the numerator. I think it would usually be $1-$.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a series. It is a rational expression of the type $a\frac{1+b}{1-b}$. *If* $|b|<1$, *then* it can be expressed as the sum of$$a(1+b)(1+b+b^2+b^3+\cdots).$$

Comment: So $a + (1+b)+$ geometric series?

Comment: I rather think that the expression reads $a\dfrac{1+b}{1-b}$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think you're right

Comment: @YvesDaoust Right. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @calcstudent No. It is $a+(1+b)\times$ a geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

You can "see" a geometric progression in any number $r$, as

$$r=\frac1{1-s}=1+s+s^2+s^3+s^4+\cdots$$ where $s=1-\dfrac1r$ (provided $r>\frac12$; but you can rescale).

So your statement is a little artificial.